# json_encode() doesn't return results?

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

So I have an array named **$subcats** like this :

```
Array
(
  [83] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id_sous_categ] => 4
                [val] => filtre a essance
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id_sous_categ] => 6
                [val] => filtre AIR
            )         
    )

  [89] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id_sous_categ] => 8
                [val] => plaquette de frein 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id_sous_categ] => 9
                [val] => disque de frien
            )

    )
)
```

When i'm doing : **$jsonSubCats = json_encode($subcats);**
The result is empty.. What am I doing wrong ?

Edit : var_dump($subcats) shows :

```
array(7) { [83]=> array(4) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id_sous_categ"]=> string(1) "4" ["val"]=> string(16) "filtre a essance" } [1]=> array(2) { ["id_sous_categ"]=> string(1) "6" ["val"]=> string(10) "filtre AIR" } [2]=> array(2) { ["id_sous_categ"]=> string(1) "7" ["val"]=> string(14) "filtre a huile" } [3]=> array(2) { ["id_sous_categ"]=> string(2) "14" ["val"]=> string(16) "filtre a gasoile" } } [89]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id_sous_categ"]=> string(1) "8" ["val"]=> string(19) "plaquette de frein " } [1]=> array(2) { ["id_sous_categ"]=> string(1) "9" ["val"]=> string(15) "disque de frien" } } [84]=> array(6) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id_sous_categ"]=> string(2) "10" ["val"]=> string(23) "huile SAE 50 5L 5000 km" } [1]=> array(2) { ["id_sous_categ"]=> string(2) "11" ["val"]=> string(23) "huile SAE 50 1L 5000 km" } [2]=> array(2) { ["id_sous_categ"]=> string(2) "12" ["val"]=> string(22) "huile 15W40 5L 7000 km" } [3]=> array(2) { ["id_sous_categ"]=> string(2) "13" ["val"]=> string(22) "huile 15w40 1L 7000 km" } [4]=> array(2) { ["id_sous_categ"]=> string(2) "15" ["val"]=> string(22) "huile 10W40 5L10000 km" } [5]=> array(2) { ["id_sous_categ"]=> string(2) "16" ["val"]=> string(22) "huile 10W40 1L10000 km" } } [91]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id_sous_categ"]=> string(2) "17" ["val"]=> string(13) "joint culasse" } [1]=> array(2) { ["id_sous_categ"]=> string(2) "18" ["val"]=> string(20) "joint cache soupape " } [2]=> array(2) { ["id_sous_categ"]=> string(2) "19" ["val"]=> string(13) "joint carter " } } [86]=> array(6) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id_sous_categ"]=> string(2) "20" ["val"]=> string(6) "avant " } [1]=> array(2) { ["id_sous_categ"]=> string(2) "21" ["val"]=> string(7) "arrier " } [2]=> array(2) { ["id_sous_categ"]=> string(2) "22" ["val"]=> string(18) "amortisseur avant " } [3]=> array(2) { ["id_sous_categ"]=> string(2) "23" ["val"]=> string(18) "amortisseur arrier" } [4]=> array(2) { ["id_sous_categ"]=> string(2) "24" ["val"]=> string(28) "biellette suspension arriere" } [5]=> array(2) { ["id_sous_categ"]=> string(2) "25" ["val"]=> string(26) "biellette suspension avant" } } [96]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id_sous_categ"]=> string(2) "26" ["val"]=> string(6) "moteur" } } [80]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id_sous_categ"]=> string(2) "27" ["val"]=> string(15) "but�e embrayage" } } }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't repro: http://codepad.org/pybXlQ7l

Comment: Are you able to provide us with the full script so that we can see if something else might be the cause?

Comment: Perhaps it's not an array of arrays but an array of objects with non public attributes.  Non public attributes will not show up after json_encode

Comment: Can you provide correct form `$subcats`

Comment: What do you mean by the correct form of $subcats ? I've edited my post with var_dump($subcats) if it can helps..

Comment: Your output says `array(7)` when you only have two elements. Something fishy is going on ;)

Comment: If json_encode or json_decode doesnt work, it is usually a really good idea to check what json_last_error() returns...

Comment: Does your code work when you do `unset($subcats[80]); echo json_encode($subcats);`

Comment: Yes ! The code is working when I'm doing `unset($subcats[80]);` ! It's also working when I'm deleting the row containing `butée embrayage` from database !

Answer (score 2):

`json_encode` fails to encode non-utf8 strings. Check your strings encoding. If that's the case, you have to either convert strings to utf8 or use your own implementation of `json_encode` (which you can quickly google by phrase "php json_encode implementation").

Comment: Thanks @pumbo ! This was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have json support enabled in your server.

Run a simple `<?php phpinfo() ?>` in any php file and search for **JSON**.

[image]

Comment: Yes, json is enabled, version 1.2.1 too. And I'm working on localhost.

Comment: can you run `var_dump($subcats)` and post output here?